# A wrong definition of infinity and a doubt about its modification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/517059/368425), @Hyperplane defined an infinite set as follows:

> Well a set $M$ is infinite if for every finite subset $U \subsetneq M$ there exists a $x \in M, x\notin U$. Consequently, you will be able to construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of distinct elements in $M$. Therefore $|M| \ge \aleph_0 $

Then @Andrés E. Caicedo commented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517040/proof-that-aleph-null-is-the-smallest-transfinite-number/517059#comment1107676_517059):

> This is not true as written. Replace $\subsetneq$ with $\subseteq$, and it will be fine now.

---

I think that @Hyperplane's definition of an infinite set is wrong. My reasoning is:

> For every subset $U \subsetneq M$, we always have $\exists x \in M, x \notin U$ by the definition of $\subsetneq$. So @Hyperplane just restated the property of $\subsetneq$ and said nothing about the definition of infinite set.

When I replace $\subsetneq$ with $\subseteq$ in @Hyperplane's answer as suggested by @Andrés E. Caicedo, I even find the new definition more awkward. My reasoning is:

> For $U=M$, there does NOT exist any $x \in M, x\notin U$. Thus the statement *Well a set $M$ is infinite if for every finite subset $U \subseteq M$ there exists a $x \in M, x\notin U$* is wrong. Let alone define an infinite set.

Could you please check whether my above reasonings are correct?

Comment: It is awkward, yes. It would be clearer if expressed as "$M$ is infinite if for every finite $U$ with $U\subseteq M,$ we have $U\subsetneq M.$"

Comment: @Cameron: Or, simply put, a set is infinite, if it is not equal to any of its finite subsets.

Comment: @CameronBuie I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907637/define-a-countably-infinite-subset-of-x for several days, but have not received any answer. Although I have some questions that are not answered such as this one. I'm very in need of getting an answer for this question. Could you please help me check it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning about the original failed definition is correct.

Your critique of the modified definition misses the point slightly. You seem to be missing the condition that $U$ has to be *finite*; so if $M$ is not finite you cannot choose $U=M$ as a *finite* subset of $M$.

On the other hand, the outcome of this is that the modified definition simply says that $M$ is infinite iff $M$ is not a finite subset of $M$. Or in other words:

> A set $M$ is called infinite if and only if it is not finite.

If we already know what "finite" means, this is a good definition. But bringing non-proper subsets into it just muddies the waters.

(On the other hand, if we *don't* already have a definition of "finite", then neither of the proposed definitions make sense).

Comment: Hi @Henning, I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907637/define-a-countably-infinite-subset-of-x for several days, but have not received any answer. Could you please help me check it out?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to think that the first given definition is wrong and you have gavin a good reason for it. However, for the corrected definition, you are not. Indeed, in order to chose $U=M$, $M$ must be finite.

Comment: Hi @nicomezi, I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907637/define-a-countably-infinite-subset-of-x for several days, but have not received any answer. Could you please help me check it out?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that if you try to choose $U=M$ and find a candidate for $x$ you fail - there aren't any elements to fit the definition of $x$, and since there are such $x$ for any finite $U$ it follows that $U=M$ cannot be finite.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907637/define-a-countably-infinite-subset-of-x for several days, but have not received any answer. Could you please help me check it out?